# Combinatorics question( The number Integer solutions of equations)

Tags: combinatorics

1)How many distinct solutions the following equation have such that $x_i \in \mathbb{N}$?
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 100 $

My answer: $\binom{ n-1}{n-k}$ where n=100, k =5 so, $\binom{99}{95} =3764376$

Is this answer correct?

2. How many distinct solutions the following equation have?

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 =100 $ such that $x_1 \in \{0,1,2,...,10\}, x_2, x_3, x_4 \in\{0,1,2,3,...\} $

How to answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part $1$ is correct

In line with the approach for part $1,$ but with the new definitions of $x_i$, 
for part $2$, the formula without restriction for $x_1$ would be $\dbinom{100+4-1}{4-1} = \dbinom{103}3$, but we need to exclude cases where $x_1 \geq 11$, so we exclude cases with $11$ preplaced in $x_1$ and the balance $92$ distributed any which way.

Thus the answer is $\dbinom{103}3 - \dbinom{92}3 = 51271$